# NFS file sharing failed on upgrade to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mount, nfs, shared-folders

I set up NFS file sharing between two Ubuntu computers on my LAN, it used to work fine. It recently stopped working (perhaps when I upgraded from Ubuntu 16 to 18?). What do I have to do different now?
On the server, the /etc/exports file looks like this:

```
/media/backup *(rw,no_subtree_check,crossmnt)
/home/files *(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

On my client machine I used to be able to mount it with a command like this:

```
mount 192.168.1.50:/home/files /media/Magrathea
```

That command now waits a loooong time, then aborts with this error message:
"mount.nfs: Connection timed out". What has changed? How do I get my sharing to work again?
(Please note, I am NOT running SAMBA, there are no Windows machines involved, using NFS between Ubuntu machines only)

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/05/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-begins-31-may-2023/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 18.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com//blog/18-04-end-of-standard-support

Answer (score 2):

Found it. The problem was not 18.04, it was the firewall. To allow NFS to share files the server must open ports 111 and 2049.

```
ufw allow 111
ufw allow 2049
```

Then I was able to mount the folders across the LAN again!